# Rigify not working correctly with new bones

Tags: rigify

I have a unique setup.  I've made a humanoid using nothing but geometry nodes.  I've got the base rig working, but when I try to add new bones (for the tail and wings), it doesn't come out right when using Rigify's Generate new mesh.
1 problem: A small section of mesh for the first bone doesn't move with the bone.
2 problem: In the wing, I used limbs.arm (and tried limbs.superlimb), and the vertex groups get all jacked up.

As it's really difficult to describe what's going on in text, I've made a video.
https://youtu.be/isr7kuUZd0I

Comment: I was able to fix the 2nd problem: In pose mode, select the first bone of the wing, set "limb segments" to 1, and renaming the 'finger' bones of the wings to "wingtip".
I still have the first problem, the weird warping at the head of the first bone of the wing and tail.

Comment: Now I just feel stupid.
I determined the behavior is exactly what one would expect to see if there were overlapping vertex groups.  But I didn't check that first, because my vertex weights are 'hard coded' inside of the Geometry node group.  But, apparently the formula I used to create the spine vertex groups caught part of the tail and wings.

Answer (score 0):

1st problem was caused by overlapping vertex groups.  Fixing the formula to exclude the wings and tail fixes the issue.

2nd problem was solved by setting "limb segments" to 1, and renaming the "finger" to wingtip and wingtip.001.